# Saving best metrics based on Custom metrics failing (WARNING:tensorflow:Can save best model only with CUSTOM METRICS available, skipping)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have defined a callback that runs on the epoch end and calculate the metrics. It is working fine in terms of calculating the desired metrics. Below is the function for reference

### callback to find metrics at epoch end

```
class Metrics(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, train_tf_data, val_tf_data, model, CLASSES, logs={}, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.train_tf_data = train_tf_data
        self.val_tf_data = val_tf_data
        self.model = model
        self.CLASSES = CLASSES
        # for train data
        self.train_f1_after_epoch = 0
        self.train_prec_after_epoch = 0
        self.train_recall_after_epoch = 0
        # for val data
        self.val_f1_after_epoch = 0
        self.val_prec_after_epoch = 0
        self.val_recall_after_epoch = 0

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.train_reports = None
        self.val_reports = None
        self.val_f1_after_epoch = 0

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        # for train data
        self.train_reports = test_model(model=self.model, data=self.train_tf_data, 
                                        CLASSES=self.CLASSES)
        self.train_f1_after_epoch = self.train_reports['f1_score']
        self.train_recall_after_epoch = self.train_reports['recall']
        self.train_prec_after_epoch = self.train_reports['precision']

        # for val data
        self.val_reports = test_model(model=self.model, data=self.val_tf_data, 
                                      CLASSES=self.CLASSES)
        self.val_f1_after_epoch = self.val_reports['f1_score']
        self.val_recall_after_epoch = self.val_reports['recall']
        self.val_prec_after_epoch = self.val_reports['precision']

        # saving train results to log dir
        logs["train_f1_after_epoch"]=self.train_f1_after_epoch
        logs['train_precision_after_epoch'] = self.train_prec_after_epoch
        logs['train_recall_after_epoch'] = self.train_recall_after_epoch
        
        # saving val results to log dir
        logs['val_f1_after_epoch'] = self.val_f1_after_epoch
        logs['val_precision_after_epoch'] = self.val_prec_after_epoch
        logs['val_recall_after_epoch'] = self.val_recall_after_epoch


        print('train_reports_after_epoch', self.train_reports)
        print('val_reports_after_epoch', self.val_reports)
```

## Code for test_model

```
def test_model(model, data, CLASSES, label_one_hot=True, average="micro"):
    images_ds = data.map(lambda image, label: image)
    labels_ds = data.map(lambda image, label: label).unbatch()
    NUM_VALIDATION_IMAGES = count_data_items(tf_records_filenames=data)
    cm_correct_labels = next(iter(labels_ds.batch(NUM_VALIDATION_IMAGES))).numpy() # get everything as one batch
    if label_one_hot is True:
        cm_correct_labels = np.argmax(cm_correct_labels, axis=-1)
    cm_probabilities = model.predict(images_ds)
    cm_predictions = np.argmax(cm_probabilities, axis=-1)
    
    # cmat = confusion_matrix(cm_correct_labels, cm_predictions, labels=range(len(CLASSES)))

    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
    score = f1_score(cm_correct_labels, cm_predictions, labels=range(len(CLASSES)), average=average)
    precision = precision_score(cm_correct_labels, cm_predictions, labels=range(len(CLASSES)), average=average)
    recall = recall_score(cm_correct_labels, cm_predictions, labels=range(len(CLASSES)), average=average)
    # cmat = (cmat.T / cmat.sum(axis=1)).T # normalized
    # print('f1 score: {:.3f}, precision: {:.3f}, recall: {:.3f}'.format(score, precision, recall))
    test_results = {'f1_score': score, 'precision':precision, 'recall':recall}
    warnings.filterwarnings('always')
    return test_results
```

## Some model code.....

## Model code

```
m1 = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
m2 = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
m3 = tf.keras.metrics.Precision()
m4 = Metrics(train_tf_data=train_data, 
             val_tf_data=test_data, model=model, 
             CLASSES=CLASS_NAMES)
optimizers = [
        tfa.optimizers.AdamW(learning_rate=lr * .001 , weight_decay=wd),
        tfa.optimizers.AdamW(learning_rate=lr, weight_decay=wd)

           ]
optimizers_and_layers = [(optimizers[0], model.layers[0]), (optimizers[1], model.layers[1:])]
    
optimizer = tfa.optimizers.MultiOptimizer(optimizers_and_layers)


model.compile(
    optimizer= optimizer,
    loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=[m1, m2, m3],
    )
```

## Using this in the callback

```
checkpoint_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path, 
                                                    monitor = 'val_f1_after_epoch',
                                                    save_best_only=True,
                                                    save_weights_only=True,
                                                    mode='max',
                                                    save_freq='epoch',
                                                    verbose=1)
                                                    
checkpoint_cb._supports_tf_logs = False
```

The issue that I am facing is that it is giving me a warning that say

**WARNING:tensorflow:Can save best model only with val_f1_after_epoch available, skipping**

Upon investigating history I found that metrics is available in the history

```
print(list(history.history.keys()))
['loss',
'categorical_accuracy',
'recall',
'precision',
'val_loss',
'val_categorical_accuracy',
'val_recall',
'val_precision',
'train_f1_after_epoch',
'train_precision_after_epoch',
'train_recall_after_epoch',
'val_f1_after_epoch', #this is the metrics
'val_precision_after_epoch',
'val_recall_after_epoch']
```

Please let me know what I am missing here, I want to save the best model based on my custom metrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the metric callback is listed before the modelcheckpoint callback.

```
history = model.fit(train_data, validation_data=test_data, epochs=N_EPOCHS, callbacks=[m4, checkpoint_cb])
```

when we passe a list of callbacks to the model,  callbacks will be called at each stage of the training. In out case Metric and ModelCheckpoint are using on_epoch_end, so you must make sure that the order of callbacks is [Metric,ModelCheckpoin]

**Note** : Metric is inheriting from callback so it will be executed only at the end of the epoch.

Comment: Yes I have listed metric callback before the modelcheckpoint. Tried using logs['val_f1_after_epoch'] = 0 but it is not working for me Even the alternative is also not working. Also the alternative you suggested is considering taking a mean by continuously updating metrics. I want to update those metrics but don't want to calculate the mean. Upon Implementation of the above code(one in code block), I am getting ValueError: SyncOnReadVariable does not support assign_add in cross-replica context when aggregation is set to tf.VariableAggregation.SUM. I am using Tensorflow 2.5.0

Comment: I tried upgarding to Tensorflow 2.7 and using turning off Mirrored strategy I am able to run the program but I am getting the same warning  . The problem is as it was. WARNING:tensorflow:Can save best model only with val_f1_after_epoch available, skipping

Comment: can you provide more details about the code i could not reproduce the error.

Comment: the only time that i get this warning is when i put` logs['val_f1_after_epoch'] = None ` in the callback

Comment: I have opened a git issue here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/15684. Please let me know in case you need some more information

Comment: I tried the code you from the issue to my own laptop ( i don't have a gpu ), i did get an error with     'ValueError: Could not interpret metric function identifier: <__main__.Metrics object at 0x000002691A79FB08>' , it's because the Metric is put in the list of metrics and it and it inherit from tf.keras.callbacks.Callback when i put the Metric in the callbacks callbacks=[m4, checkpoint_cb] the error did get away and the model did save. can you provide some insight about the "test_model" function

Comment: what i think it's causing the problem is that the model is still evaluating in some tpus may be and the epoch 2 is starting before the evaluation in some way. can you remove the model from the __init__, when you enherit the callback you can directly use self.model. https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/

Comment: Thanks for your assitance. I have added the code for test_model in the question itself. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried removing the model from __init__  and the results are the same. Getting the same warning. WARNING:tensorflow:Can save best model only with val_f1_after_epoch available, skipping. No model saving is happening

Comment: any update on this ? i couldn't reproduce the error unfortunately

Comment: I have created a colab notebook to replicate the error. Please have a look at it here https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-6qcPFv2BrdenRm6ncFUfNxDdquJO4l7?usp=sharing

Comment: can you please grant me access.

Comment: Oops, I missed that. I have been granted access now. Thanks

Comment: can you have a look at this https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OEcwkGoDOtC8GP9hYE4JWDhXvjIImE3E?usp=sharing here the model is saving.

Comment: Yes it is working Now, can you please explain what changes leads to this solution?

Comment: first of all i added  steps_per_epoch and validation_steps this help to keep track of the training processe of the model and keep track of the epochs, i changed the monitor to 'val_f1_after_epoch' it was on 'accuracy' on the original notebook and i added the metric to the callbacks callbacks=[m4,checkpoint_cb] the metric must be before the modelcheckpoint

Comment: Even if I change the monitory to 'val_f1_after_epoch' it is not solving the problem. So the workaround is something related to steps_per_epochs and validation_steps. Isn't it ?